como mostrar imágenes locales en angular 18
Hola estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen en mi web desde la carpeta assets que cree en public hago la referencia desde img en src no me muestra nada... por último e intentado utilizar la optimización impotando en appmodule a "NgOptimizedImage" y usando ngSrc y nada... lo tengo de la siguiente manera
y me sigue mostrando, lo siguiente:
cualquier tipo de ayuda le estaré muy agradecida

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

yo creo que seria mejor si nos das contexto de tu codigo.. pero bueno a ciegas vamos a ver si te puedo ayudar con unos puntos..
EJEMPLIFICANDO

revisa bien de neuvo que la imagen este ubicada en la carpeta assets dentro de la carpeta src de tu proyecto angular (src/assets/ricxrdo.jpg)
en el html donde deseas mostrar la imagen utiliza la etiqueta <img>, y asegurate de que el atributo src este correctamente referenciado ejemplo basico:


<img src="assets/ricxrdo.jpg">



en el uso de ngsrc con ngoptimizedimage para la optimizacion verifica si implementas bien el modulo por ejemplo:


import { NgOptimizedImage } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ (en esta parte van tus componentes) ],
  imports: [ (aca otros modulos) NgOptimizedImage ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



tambien en tu html usa ngsrc en lugar de src:


<img ngSrc="assets/ricxrdo.jpg">


ojo revisar tus subcarpetas en caso de que este la imagen metida por ahi

por ultimo lo que se me ocurre es verificar la integridad de la imagen que cargue directamente en el navegador para verificar que la ruta funciona por ejemplo no se:


http://localhost/assets/ricxrdo.jpg


sin nada de codigo de contexto es lo mas basico que se me puede ocurrir, lo siento si te confundo mas.
